# JMeter HTML Report creation using Taurus Runner Task in Azure Pipelines

Tags: jmeter, azure-pipelines, taurus

Does anyone knows how to generate Jmeter HTML Report using Taurus Runner Task in Azure Pipelines. I can create this Jmeter HRML report using Jmeter CLI.

my taurus yaml config is
***execution:

- scenario:
  script: _JmeterTest/JmeterWebApp.jmx
  concurrency: 4
  iterations: 1
  ramp-up: 2s
  reporting:
- module: junit-xml
  filename: taurus-output/TEST-Taurus.xml***

I heard somehwhere to using ShellExec module but not sure how to use it in my case.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Example configuration for the [ShellExec](https://gettaurus.org/docs/ShellExec/) module would be something like:

```
services:
- module: shellexec
  post-process:
  - ~/.bzt/jmeter-taurus/5.2.1/bin/./jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=false -g ${TAURUS_ARTIFACTS_DIR}/kpi.jtl -o /tmp/dashboard
```

This [jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message property override](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/) is required in order to make Taurus results configuration compatible with JMeter's default [results file configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)

Comment: Not using Taurus plugin except Jmeter in the pipeline, just wondering if you have used publishhtmlreport task in azure release pipeline, I am trying my best but some reason it is  not working.

Comment: ShellExec will work only with Linux Agent not with windows agent